# Plugin fieldtype settings for ColumnType::LongText being inserted as varchar(255)

Tags: plugin-development, fieldtypes, custom-fieldtype

I’m working on a plugin that includes a custom fieldtype. Using Craft 2.6.2911, the fieldtype’s `defineSettings` looks like this:

```
public function defineSettings ( ) {
    return [
        'json_data'  =>  [
            AttributeType::String,
            'column'  =>  ColumnType::LongText
        ]
    ];
}
```

When I add this field to a tab group, the new column is added to the `craft_content` table as a `varchar(255)`, not a `text`-type column.  Is there an additional definition I need somewhere?

I did not see a relevant note in the changelog for builds of Craft between 2.6.2911 and 2.6.2944.

When reviewing my database schema, I'm seeing the following:

```
| field_jsonSync             | varchar(255)           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Field Types `defineSettings` method defines the settings that get handled when you create the field. Those field settings get stored as `json` in the `craft_fields.settings` column when the field is created.

The `BaseFieldType` class has another method you can add to your class called `defineContentAttribute`. In your case, getting the column to be the data type you want would look like:

```
public function defineContentAttribute()
{
    return [
        AttributeType::String,
        'column'  =>  ColumnType::LongText
    ];
}
```

The `PlainTextFieldType` and `RichTextFieldType` classes have similar use cases which modify the default `defineContentAttribute` value if you want to take a look at a few more examples.

Comment: This was exactly what I had overlooked. Implementing this resolved my problem. Thank you.